# How to hide elements by clicking on other items while using toggle?

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

I have two problems with the fiddle below:
https://jsfiddle.net/vitordhers/cwpgL94o/2/

I'm using the code below as a script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#option1").click(function () {
        $("#p1").toggle(500);
    });
});
$(function() {
    $("#option2").click(function () {
        $("#p2").toggle(500);
    });
});
$(function() {
    $("#option3").click(function () {
        $("#p3").toggle(500);
    });
});
</script>
```

1st: I need to display #p1 as soon the page is loaded, since #option1 is selected. How is that possile?;

2nd: How can #p1 hide itself whenever I click on other element besides #option1?

I've been trying to use jquery since it's more simple than javascript, please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your css so you aren't hiding `#p1` by default, and set `selected` on the first option.

Set a value on each `option` that represents the paragraph to show, and on `change` of the `select`, if the element you want to show is hidden, hide all of them and show the one you selected.

```js
$(function() {

  $('select').on('change', function() {
    var $target = $('#p' + $(this).val());
    if ($target.is(":hidden")) {
      $('p').hide();
      $target.show();
    }
  })

});
```

```css
#p2,
#p3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select mutiple size="3">
  <option id="option1" selected value="1"> Option 1</option>
  <option id="option2" value="2"> Option 2</option>
  <option id="option3" value="3"> Option 3</option>
</select>

<p id="p1"> Thanks for choosing option 1</p>
<p id="p2"> Thanks for choosing option 2</p>
<p id="p3"> Thanks for choosing option 3</p>
```

Comment: If you&#39;re going to show `$target` after hiding the others, you might as well delete the `.not($target)`... Right?

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon you can if you want. In some cases, that might cause a flicker, so I always try to exclude the thing I'm trying to show when I hide elements. You could also just check to see if the element you want to show is visible already and abort if it is.

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon went ahead and updated my answer to just check if the element is visible. Seems like the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: thanks, man, that was really useful. As per what I've been told change events are supported in IE and Safari, is that correct?

Comment: @HugoDiMarkDhers you bet. Yeah `change` is a super standard browser event, supported across the board as far as I know, implemented many years ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this small code:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#opt").click(function () {
        var txt = $("#opt").find(":selected").text();
        $("#selected").text(txt);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="opt" mutiple size="3">
<option id="option1" selected> Option 1</option>
<option id="option2"> Option 2</option>
<option id="option3"> Option 3</option>
</select>

<p id="p">Thanks for choosing  
    <span id="selected">Option 1</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```js
$(function() {
 var $options = $('.option'),
      $ps = $('.p');
    $options.click(function () {
     var ind = $options.index(this),
       $target = $ps.eq(ind);
      $ps.slideUp(500);
      if (!$target.is(':visible')) {
       $target.slideDown(500);
      }
    });
    $options.eq(0).click();
});
```

```css
.p{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select mutiple size="3">
<option class="option"> Option 1</option>
<option class="option"> Option 2</option>
<option class="option"> Option 3</option>
</select>

<p class="p"> Thanks for choosing option 1</p>
<p class="p"> Thanks for choosing option 2</p>
<p class="p"> Thanks for choosing option 3</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try It:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select option').click(function(){
        $('#p1,#p2,#p3').hide(500);
        $('select ~ p').eq($(this).index()).show(1000);
    })
})
```

```css
#p1, #p2, #p3 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select mutiple size="3">
<option id="option1"> Option 1</option>
<option id="option2"> Option 2</option>
<option id="option3"> Option 3</option>
</select>

<p id="p1"> Thanks for choosing option 1</p>
<p id="p2"> Thanks for choosing option 2</p>
<p id="p3"> Thanks for choosing option 3</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function() {
    $("#option1").click(function () {
        $("p").hide();
        $("#p1").show();
    });
});
$(function() {
    $("#option2").click(function () {
        $("p").hide();
        $("#p2").show();
    });
});
$(function() {
    $("#option3").click(function () {
        $("p").hide();
        $("#p3").show();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#option1').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Your code is quite buggy. If I click P1 twice, it will hide the paragraph, but P1 will still be selected

Comment: Also, if you click P2 then change to p3, both paragraphs will be showing.